# Why are services set to "automatic" not starting when I boot up Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, sp3, services

I have a fresh install of Windows XP.

My problem is that every time I start it up, I have to go into Administrative Tools and start the needed services, such as DCOM, RTP, DHCP, etc. The **only** services that start automatically are:

- plug and play
- remote procedure
- server
- windows audio
- workstation

All of the rest have to be started manually, in spite of the fact that they're listed as `automatic` startup. Why won't they start on their own, like they should?

Comment: What do the system and application event logs show?  Any errors relating to those services starting?

Comment: those services are among the services which do not start.

Comment: Have you tried safe mode? (The Event log service and a few others should auto start in safe mode as well). Perhaps try system restore to go back to JUST after the XP install was finished and see how they act?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was: Windows had not installed correctly, for one reason or another. While the OS booted and worked for the most part, a lot of things (msconfig itself, for example) were quite simply missing. A reinstall of Windows fixed the problem.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the Log On as account within each service.  Are the services that are starting correctly using the same account as the ones that aren't?

Comment: i'm not sure, i'll have to check... but these services start if i start them from the Services window in Administrative Tools. In any case, I'll get back to you

Comment: There is no discernible difference - mostly they're all using the system account, and some of those start automatically, but most of them don't

Answer (score 0):

If you run msconfig, you can setup the proper services that you need on startup. You should check and make sure that they are enabled there.

You can also run services.msc to get to your services menu, but it sounds like you've already checked that judging by how you say that they're set to automatic.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the msconfig setting check in "Service" tab & StartUP Tab